# Is there a redux-saga alternative for react hooks state management solution

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

By using React 16 hooks, I can get rid of redux but still to have a state management feature, refer to: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react

However, I used to use redux-saga to have a listener(or handler) to do something async after the reducer processed an action. The question is I am not sure how to achieve this if not relying on redux, redux-saga.

In another words, if looking into the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4qzj73lozx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2F05-context-with-reducer.js

How to listen to the "increase" action, to do something async when it happens (without using redux-saga).

Comment: If you're talking about having something after a state update, then it may depend on how you're using react to manage your state.

Answer (score 3):

I am using redux & redux-saga for async operations, which is very comfortable in terms of readability, debugging, and modularity of my code. However, if you want to use hooks to handle that, it is possible as well by creating a custom hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useAsyncHook() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(
          `ENDPOINT`
        );

        const data = await res.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return [data, loading];
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
function App() {
  const [data, loading] = useAsyncHook();
  return (
    <div>
      {!loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {data && data.map(item => {
          return <div>{item}</div>;
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```